# It is considering quotes ("%d") as undefined ascii symbol when I am compiling it on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, double-quotes

Eg. When I write this-> `scanf(“%d”,&newnode->x);`

Error is,

```
list.c:18:7: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
scanf(“%d”,&newnode->x);
      ^
list.c:18:10: error: expected expression
scanf(“%d”,&newnode->x);
       ^
list.c:18:12: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals
      and identifiers
scanf(“%d”,&newnode->x);
         ^
list.c:18:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'd'
scanf(“%d”,&newnode->x);
        ^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: Did you use Word to write your code? Or copy it in Outlook? Those programs have a nasty habbit of changing "..." to "correct" quotation marks for text. But they are only correct for text, not for programming languages.

Comment: I simply write in the pre-installed Text Editor and use quotation marks " " as they are on the keyboard. How to change them to ascii code which the terminal accepts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, you have a problem with `”` ( unicode quote, U+201C ) over the expected `"` ( ascii quote, U+0022 ). They are not really the same.

You can read the differences in detail [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html).